# How to tell ElasticSearch to make certain string queries the same as others

Tags: elasticsearch

For example:

If I type **US** (as in United States) as my search query, but in my DB it is written as **U.S.**, then ES won't match the term.

So I am wondering: is there a way to tell ES that **US** is equivalent to **U.S.**?

Other examples: Making **CAD** equivalent to **Canada** and **cdn**

Comment: Use Synonym Token Filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use synonyms available in ES.

Refer to doc - 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html